# TPC DS queries and database

Tags: database, bigdata, database-schema, tpc

Where can I find TPC DS queries and the dataset?   It’s for one of my project work, where I need to analyze their performance on redshift and snowflake.

Comment: The set of 99 queries along with the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the dataset generator and queries [on the TPC website](http://www.tpc.org/tpc_documents_current_versions/current_specifications.asp)

Also, Snowflake comes with TPC-DS (and some other datasets) available to all users, see [this article](https://www.snowflake.net/tpc-ds-now-available-snowflake-samples/)

Comment: By default, Snowflake comes with 10 TB and 100 TB scale of TPC-DS datasets, is it possible to get the same with less volume(10 GB or lesser than that)? If so, where can I get it? Thanks in advance!